# How does devise's remember_user_token work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise

When I see rails log I see only 1 sql for authorized user, like:

```
 User Load (44.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

And I could find in my browser cookie: remember_user_token with random string. But how rails understands that it's user with id=1?

Comment: Does your user model have a column `authenticatable_salt` or `remember_token` ? How does your user model look like?

Comment: no, only login and encrypted password in the DB

Answer (score 0):

The random string stored in browser cookie is encoded with user_id and remember_token, so the devise can get user_id after the random string is decoded.